# Prove that $k = \sup(S)$

Tags: real-analysis

$$S=\left\{\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n} \, \Big| \, m,n>0 \text{ and } m,n  \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$; and let $K$ be a number with the
following properties:

- for each positive integer $n$; the number $K-(1/n)$ is not an upper bound
  of $S$ and
- for each positive integer $n$; the number $K +(1/n)$ is an upper bound of
  $S$.

Prove that $K = \sup S$.

Been pulling my hair out trying to show that $K=\sup(S)$ but I haven't anything intelligent. A tug in the right direction please?

Comment: Is $S$ an arbitrary nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$, or is it the set you wrote in the first line?

Answer (score 1):

If $K<\sup S$, then there exists $n,\ m$ s.t.
$$ K< 1/n-1/m $$

So there exists $M$ s.t. $$ K < K+\frac{1}{M} < 1/n-1/m $$ which
contradicts to the second condition.

If $K> \sup S$ then there exists $M$ s.t. $K > K- \frac{1}{M} >
1/n-1/m $ for every $1/n-1/m\in S$. $K- \frac{1}{M}$ is an upper
bound, which contradicts to the first condition.

Comment: why there is $M$ such $ K < K+\frac{1}{M} < 1/n-1/m$ ?

Comment: Let $1/n -1/m -K =\delta >0$ then there exists $M>0$ s.t. $1/M <\delta$ (cf. archimedean property)